# Using Jquery submit with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

When the user clicks the 'submit' button on my form, I would like 'this will be echoed back' to be displayed within an alert.

The only JS console error I get:

`Failed to load resource http://nikkomsgchannel/e?0017005e002b00560036004400190026002d0025002c005300…240020003700620024005b004a005500790053002c0045002b003600300026002f005d004c`

The only code I've changed is the Jquery, before this I was using a hyperlink & `click`event in Jquery, which was working.

My code:

PHP file

```
function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script( "ajax-test", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/ajax-test.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-test', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );  
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files"); 

function text_ajax_process_request() {
            if ( isset( $_POST["post_var"] ) ) {
        $response = $_POST["post_var"];
        echo $response;
        die();
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_test_response', 'text_ajax_process_request');

function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'displaycalcs', 'mp_calcs_display' );
}
    function mp_calcs_display() {

            $output = <<<HTML
            <form action="" method="post" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >
    Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
 Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" id="numberofconwelds"  >
   Total one: <input type="text" name="totalone" id="totalone" disabled>
<div id="totalfail1"></div>
   Total two: <input type="text" name="totaltwo" id="totaltwo" disabled>
<div id="totalfail2"></div>
   Total three: <input type="text" name="totalthree" id="totalthree" disabled>
<div id="totalfail3"></div>
   <input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="submit" name="submit" >
<div id="result"> </div>
</form> 
 HTML;
return $output;
}
```

**ajax-test.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $("#submit").submit( function() {
        var data = {
            action: 'test_response',

                        post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
        };
                $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that your domain? And the address is definitely not that set by `wp_localize_script`. Not to be paranoid, but I can't help but think you have a malware problem.

Comment: No, I don't recognise that address at all. Sorry to be naive, but a malware problem on my hosting or computer?

Comment: Honestly, it could be either. Try accessing/testing the site from another computer to narrow that down.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll look into it . Have you got any ideas about my ajax Q please? I've only changed the jquery, & it worked previously.

Comment: That _was_ about your AJAX question.

Comment: The http://nikkomsgchannel/ request appears to be due to 'Trusteer Rapport' software, software used by a number of (big) banks to help ensure the security of their users when transmitting data over the internet. So that request you're seeing is coming from that when you try to submit form data.

Comment: youre using rapport secure in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error was identified by stackoverflow - it's actually caused by Rapport software, a security tool some banks recommend. You could turn it off / remove it from development machines.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems:

Don't `echo` things in the AJAX callback. JavaScript should handle that.

To send data in your callback, use `wp_send_json()` or the higher level functions `wp_send_json_success()` and `wp_send_json_error()`. All of them will `die` for you. No need to `exit` or `die` afterwards.

Data Validation and Sanitization is something you should take serious: `$response = $_POST["post_var"];` is ***extremely unsafe*** way to do things. If you already got hacked, then this would have been an open door. Use `filter_var()` or `filter_var_array()`, both native PHP functions, or `esc_attr()` and similar WordPress escaping functions.

AJAX and shortcodes are a very specific thing. Per default AJAX requests go through the admin interface (hence `admin-ajax.php` as handling route). And shortcodes aren't needed in the admin UI. They get rendered during runtime when the content of a post gets rendered when looping. See [search results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax+shortcode).

Comment: @mattnewbie I edited [the gist](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/6902888) to be a plugin. The only thing needed would be something like `add_action( 'loop_start', array( $this, 'renderForm' ) );` and some actual form inside `renderForm()` to pass data around. Should be enough to help you start playing around.